# How to get a CustomControl into SuiteBarBrandingDelegate with MDS-Feature activated?

Tags: 2013, user-controls, mds, minimal-download-strategy, suitebar

I want to add a Navigation to the SuiteBarBrandingDelegate. I created a nicely working solution for this but it doesn't work with the MDS-Feature activated (Minimal download strategy).

After some research I looked up my masterpage and found out that the "SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" is not surrounded with an AjaxDelta-Tag. After Adding it everything works nice again.

Now one of my problems is that there will be like 100 Sitecollection at the end and no one will ever customize this number of collections ;-)
How could I solve this Problem? Deploy masterpages for the Portal and Mysites?

I also tried to wrap my Control itself with the AjaxDelta-Tag but this results in breaking on some Jscripts while loading the site. Which leads me to my fully loaded /sitepages/homepage.aspx.

Is there a way to fix this? I use a Site-scoped feature. Should I change this? 
And deactivating MDS is not an option ;-)

Comment: What is your solution today? A delegate control should not be affected by MDS

Comment: it's a user control sry wrong tag